# py.test and fixtures - how to choose only one variant of params

Tags: python, pytest

Let's say I have following fixtures:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=['google.com','other-provider.com')
def smtp_server(request):
    .... some initialisation ....
    return SmtpServer(request.param)


@pytest.fixture(params=['plain_text','html')
def message(request):
    .... some initialisation according to email type....
    return msg_obj
```

So if I use them in one test function, I have combination: google+plain, provider+plain, google+html, provider+html.

But what if I want to reuse fixtures, but only in specific combination. Eg I noticed that when I send html email to google, it fails under some circumstances. How can I reuse fixtures and test this situation, without testing sending to other-provider.com, which is pointless?

In other words - how to skip some combination of fixtures in specific test function?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I'd like to point out this is actually a fairly odd case.  Are you really sure the tests are not meaningful at all for the combinations you want to skip?

Having said that the way I have solved this myself is to simply use

```
if snmtp_server == 'other-provider.com' and message == 'html':
    pytest.skip('impossible combination')
```

inside the test function.  It's rudimentary but works good enough for this unusual and rare case.

Comment: Well, I need it every time I write pytest tests. Your solution works, until I have fixtures which takes lot of time/resources/cpu power to prepare. Eg - fixture "big_file" which is file object of 1/2/3/5/10G file